# How to load image with TextField and center it actionscript

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash

I need to load images within my Flash project 
I don't want to use the Loader class cause the images are from a different domain.

I load images with a TextField 
Here is my code:

```
var ti:TextField = new TextField();
ti.border=1
ti.htmlText += " <img id='movieInTxt' align='center' src='"+pic+"' />";
allMC[counter].img.addChild(ti);
```

I am loading the images to movieClip in a shape of a box.
I want to position the image in the center.
How can I make it ?

I tried `ti.autoSize =  TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER` but it doesn't work...

Any suggestions how to load an image and position it in the center ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<p align='center'><img /></p>` I guess.

You can totally use a Loader on domain you don't own since you don't access any advanced properties on the image (like pixel-level manipulations). You can then access the size of the image, and center it in your container.

[AS3 doc](http://as3.blue112.eu/flash/display/Loader.html) says :

> **You can load content from any accessible source.**
>
> If the loaded content is an image, its data cannot be accessed by a SWF file outside of the security sandbox, unless the domain of that SWF file was included in a cross-domain policy file at the origin domain of the image.

You can force flashplayer to not check `crossdomain.xml` file by passing `false` in the `LoaderContext` constructor :

```
myLoader.load(urlReq, new LoaderContext(false));
```

Comment: <p align='center'> dosent working.. 
how can i use loader to load image from diffrent domain without having cross domain issue ?

Comment: You don't need to do anything, just use normally the loader : It won't complain if you don't try to access protected properties in the image. I'm editing my answer.

Comment: great, i changed my code. i use the loader and it working.
but how can i access the image width and height in order to make it in the center ?

Comment: You have to wait for the Event.COMPLETE event to be dispatched, then you'll just use loader.content.height and loader.content.width. Don't forget to upvote and validate if its answering your question.

Comment: Yes thank you, that helped

var lod = new Loader();
lod.load(new URLRequest(pic));
lod.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
and then i used 
e.target.content.height